# Which preposition should I use (during/on the time)

Tags: prepositions

Context: Teachers set their schedules in an electronic calendar by showing the time slots they can teach. And we've noticed that these time slots are very popular among students. Which preposition should I use in these sentences:
"Students are really eager to schedule lessons during/on the time (slots) you set."
"Most students book lessons during/on the time you set."

I tried to google the information, but the only explanations I find are about "on/in time". I didn't manage to find anything helpful.

Comment: It depends entirely on if you add *time* to the sentence. I would say this: *Students are really eager to schedule lessons **in** the time slots you set.* But without *slots*: *Students are really eager to schedule lessons **at** the **times** you set.* (Note that the use of *slots* changes noun *times* to the attributive noun *time*.)

Comment: I see. And if I say that _students already book lessons at the time you set_?
_Most students book lessons at the time (times?) you set_. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: That's also grammatical. I will say that the entire construction, regardless of the specific wording, is a little odd. I would find something like these more natural: (1) *Most students will try to take advantage of any free time you have.* (2) *If you have a free time slot, it's likely some student will book it.* However, that doesn't address prepositions. (Although note this: *I booked an appointment **during** one of your **free periods**.* That's yet another preposition in a different construction; unfortunately, there is no clear rule that I can spell out for this.)

Comment: "During" to me modifies the verb "book" so as to affect the time when the activity takes place so I interpret "Students are keen to book lessons _during_ the time slots you set as meaning that they have their phones out booking future slots while they are in your class.  I assume that that is not what you mean to say.

Comment: I'd suggest 'using' or, if a regular preposition is felt to be better, 'within'.

Comment: "During" is not what I want, I guess. I want to describe how popular the time slots that tutors opened are.